# What can I do to speed up my internet connection?

Tags: 11.10

I tried doing this: http://www.hitxp.com/articles/software/ubuntu-fix-slow-wireless-internet-connection-speed-upgrading-11-04-natty-narwhal/ and to check if it was bufferbloat but my internet is still so slow. I have a 'Sony vaio i3 core model:VPCEB23FM'

What can I do to speed it up?

Comment: Could you tell us the name of your wlan stick or card?

Comment: Ask your Internet provider for a faster connection or use wired Internet instead of wireless.

Answer (score 1):

These steps will enable the Google Domain server, The resoning is that everyone uses the default domain name server that you ISP provides, and may take longer to look up names for web addresses, espasally during high traffic times. This will not however make your connection "faster", you might or might not notice faster finding of a webpage.

1. Alt+F2 and run `gksu gedit /etc/resolv.conf`
2. Copy and paste the following lines:

   ```
   nameserver 8.8.8.8
   nameserver 8.8.4.4
   ```
3. Restart your computer and that's all.

References:

- http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/google_launches_google_public_dns_opendns_competitor.php

Comment: Can you elaborate this answer to explain what this does (uses Google's DNS)?